# Unable to execute bash script inside expect script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, expect

i have a expect script like

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
.....
spawn passwd
expect "password:"
send "password"
....
....
....
~/test.sh
```

Wile executing this, I'm unable to run bash script `test.sh`.

How to execute Linux commands/bash scripts inside Expect script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with you should use `spawn` to run your script, and I'm not certain the tilde construct will be interpreted by expect.

```
spawn /bin/bash /home/username/test.sh
```

You should have error messages when this happens, you should add the to your question if you do not understand them.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the tcl `exec` command, which normally collects the output, so redirect it:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
...
exec ~/test.sh  >@stdout
```

Comment: I didn't think of exec. I suppose it depends on what Dinesh wants to do. Redirects here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554304/what-is-the-difference-between-spawn-and-exec